# making a span behave like a button

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<div class="btns">

<div id="green">    <span class="btn btn-block btn-large btn-success disabled green_btn">Green</span>

 <div class="num">(1)</div>
</div>
<div id="red">
    <form class="button_to" >
        <div>
            <input class="btn btn-block btn-large btn-danger red_btn"
            type="submit" value="Red">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="num">(0)</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.btns {
    position: relative;
}

.num {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#green, #red {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    position: relative;
}

.green_btn, .red_btn {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

I can't figure out why the (1) under green span isn't behaving like (0) under the red button. If I remove `bottom:0;` it fixes the green but messes up red.

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/HajHV/

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you also tell us, what you are trying to do? Are you trying to align them in same line?

Comment: yes, (1) should be centered under green the same as (0) is centered under the red button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the form's margin.

```
margin: 0 0 20px;
```

Comment: any idea why green and red are not aligned in firefox?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
.btn
{
    background-color: rgb(7, 55, 99);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px 12px 3px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

HTML

```
<span class="btn">Submit</span>
```

after removing the output output is 
[image]

Comment: remove 

form
{ 
margin:0 0 20px;
}

and add

<div id="green" style="float:left;">
<div id="red" style="float:right;">

Answer (score 4):

Twitter Bootstrap (which you are using) adds some bottom margin to the the `<form>` element.

Try this to normalize the two buttons:

```
.button_to { margin-bottom:0; } /* Target the <form> in the red button */
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HajHV/3/

Comment: any idea why green and red are not aligned in firefox?

Comment: Changing `display:inline-block` to `float:left` corrects it, but actually I'm not sure why it's so off in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="num" style="height:5px;">(1)</div>
```

Use it in your `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is the problem of form's margin. I removed your CSS and simply added this:

```css
form { margin: 0; }
#green, #red {
    width: 48%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
.num { margin: 0 auto; width: 10px; }
```

[Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/HajHV/4/)